# Copying files over the network is MUCH slower with `file.copy` than `system(mv ...)`

Tags: r, drive

I have been having some issues with R becoming very sluggish when accessing files over our corporate network. So I dropped back and did some testing and I was shocked to discover that the R `file.copy()` command is ***much*** slower than the equivalent file copy using `system(mv ...)`. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong here?

Here's my test:

I have three files:

- *large_random.txt*  - ~100 MB
- *medium_random.txt* - ~10 MB
- *small_random.txt*  - ~1 MB

I created these on my Mac like so:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=small_random.txt bs=1048576 count=1
dd if=/dev/urandom of=medium_random.txt bs=1048576 count=10
dd if=/dev/urandom of=large_random.txt bs=1048576 count=100
```

But the following R tests were all done using Windows running in a virtual machine. The *J:* drive is local and the *N:* drive is 700 miles (1100 km) away.

```r
library(tictoc)

test_copy <- function(source, des){
  tic('r file.copy')
  file.remove(des)
  file.copy(source, des )
  toc()

  tic('system call')
  system(paste('rm', des, sep=' '))
  system(paste('cp', source, des, sep=' '))
  toc()
}

source <- 'J:\\tidy_examples\\dummyfiles\\small_random.txt'
des <- 'N:\\JAL\\2018\\_temp\\small_random.txt'
test_copy(source, des)

source <- 'J:\\tidy_examples\\dummyfiles\\medium_random.txt'
des <- 'N:\\JAL\\2018\\_temp\\medium_random.txt'
test_copy(source, des)

source <- 'J:\\tidy_examples\\dummyfiles\\large_random.txt'
des <- 'N:\\JAL\\2018\\_temp\\large_random.txt'
test_copy(source, des)
```

Which results in the following:

```
> source <- 'J:\\tidy_examples\\dummyfiles\\small_random.txt'
> des <- 'N:\\JAL\\2018\\_temp\\small_random.txt'
> test_copy(source, des)
r file.copy: 6.49 sec elapsed
system call: 2.12 sec elapsed
>
> source <- 'J:\\tidy_examples\\dummyfiles\\medium_random.txt'
> des <- 'N:\\JAL\\2018\\_temp\\medium_random.txt'
> test_copy(source, des)
r file.copy: 56.86 sec elapsed
system call: 4.65 sec elapsed
>
> source <- 'J:\\tidy_examples\\dummyfiles\\large_random.txt'
> des <- 'N:\\JAL\\2018\\_temp\\large_random.txt'
> test_copy(source, des)
r file.copy: 562.94 sec elapsed
system call: 31.01 sec elapsed
>
```

So what's going on that makes the system call so much faster? At the large file size it's more than 18 times slower!

Comment: Interesting. Is it safe to assume that fs caching is not a factor? (What if you reverse the order of `file.copy`/`system`?) Are both `J:` and `N:` network drives? Are the use of `file.remove` and `system("rm...")` similarly a problem (different, similar, ...)? What if you remove them from the tic/toc timing (or time them on their own)?

Comment: Good questions. J is local & N is networked. The rm takes no time, it’s all in the copy.

Comment: R implements it's own file copy, so it could be just inefficient with network I/O. With these lines of code it looks like it uses a pretty small buffer for windows, which would cause slow transfers (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/48499cfb5a9098dc6879a1fb517be3df5c146ab5/src/main/platform.c#L375). Finding this was the extent of my C knowledge though, so I'm not sure how it's actually implemented in the end.

Comment: Exacerbated by the fact that R's `system` and `system2` are a bit broken (e.g., whitespace). JD, I have not tried it, but I wonder if [`fs`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/index.html) would perform any better.

Comment: `mingw` `mv` (via `coretools`) which is really `cp` which calls underlying `copy` code that eventually computes a buffer size — even under Windows — uses (IIRC) 8K vs the 512b @Shawn noted. That's def going to have an impact (and not in gd way) for `file.copy()`.

Comment: everything above was in bog standard R GUI in Windows. But I've noticed terrible performance when running RStudio on a proj that's located on a network share. All the RStudio panes become laggy as hell. I wonder if this is related...

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same problem with low performance of file.copy over network share drives. My solution was to use [fs::file_copy()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fs/versions/1.3.1/topics/copy) instead which performed even slightly better than the direct system call of copy.

Comment: I confirm the `fs` solution solved the problem, however it would be nice to understand what happens with standard `file.copy`